# iOS Swift: How to implement "Cash out" method from My App?

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

I want to build an app that distributes money to users after completing some tasks or after completing some game or something. Does anybody knows how to do "cashouts" from an app through paypal or by any other method.

However I did found a method with "paypal payout option". https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/large-batch-payouts/#

I just want to know whether this would help me meet my requirement?

Comment: Note that Apple has a pretty expansive view of what constitutes a "gambling app" and they've added extra restrictions, including that they cannot be submitted by individual developers. I've had apps that give away promotional prizes in a drawing get marked by Apple as "gambling." Just something to dig into to make sure you won't be hit with a business plan rejection (they're really annoying…)

Answer (score -1):

Using Paypal, its possible to do payments but sometimes its tricky with third party integration of batch payments, you can implement wallet in your app and use Apple pay to process the payments steady and easy to way to manage payments.

Ref Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit

To send money between accounts: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/payments